# tabView: event.getTab() always null with Mojarra 2.3 - Alternatives?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, wildfly, mojarra

I've been stuck with this issues for past three years (since WildFly 16.x ~).

tabView: event.getTab() null in Mojarra 2.3 #3800
https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/3800

My own code:

```
<p:tabView switchType="ajax" id="tabViewHome" headerPosition="top" headerLocation="center" style="width:100%">            
    <p:ajax process="@parent" event="tabChange" listener="#{tabsChangesController.onTabChange}" update=":formNOTiFY:msgs"/>
    <p:ajax process="@parent" event="tabClose" listener="#{tabsChangesController.onTabClose}" update=":formNOTiFY:msgs"/>

    <p:tab title="Motorcycles" id="motorcycles">
        <ui:include src="SelectMotorcycles.xhtml"/>
    </p:tab>

    <p:tab title="Display Selected Motorcycle" id="selectedMotorcycles" closable="true">
        <ui:include src="DisplaySelectedMotorcycle.xhtml"/>
    </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

Calls:

```
public void onTabChange(TabChangeEvent event) {
   LOGGER.info(">>>>> TabChangeEvent event = {}", event);
}
```

Results in 'null':

```
SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (default task-1) javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @38,136 listener="#{tabsChangesController.onTabChange}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'tabsChangesController' resolved to null
```

PrimeFace Showcase 10.0.0 & 11.0.0-RC1 '**TabView**' works on Mojarra 2.3 & MyFaces with Jetty:

```
mvn clean jetty:run -Pnon-ee,mojarra-2.3
```

https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/tree/master/primefaces-showcase

Is Mojarra & WildFly likely to be fixed? Or how easy is it to switch to Jetty or similar on **WildFly 25.0.0.Final**?

I use:

```
PrimeFace (Elite) 10.0.7/11.0.0-RC1 
Mojarra JSF 2.3.14.SP04 & OmniFaces 3.11.2 
WildFly 25.0.0.Final (EE 8/9), Weld 4.0.2 (Final) & CDI 3.0 
Java OpenJDK 17, Kotlin 1.5.31, Gradle 7.2, MongoDB 5.0.3
IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.3, macOS Big Sur 11.6
```

Comment: Why not just upgrade Mojarra in Wildfly to 2.3.16?  That is relatively easy to do in the modules directory.

Comment: Can you point where "jsf-impl-2.3.16.jar" is on mvn? TIA

Comment: ```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.faces</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.16</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I was hoping I could just use com/sun/jsf-impl/main/jsf-impl-2.3.14.SP04.jar -> jsf-impl-2.3.16.jar (or similar). I'm not using Jakarta 'per se' as it requires more effort as listed by Brian Stansberry @ lists.jboss.org/archives/list/wildfly-dev@lists.jboss.org/… & Hibernate ORM 5.5.0.Final released @ in.relation.to/2021/06/02/hibernate-orm-550-final-release. Also WildFly EE 9 uses: jsf-impl-3.0.0.SP04. Looks like it requires more effort. Thanks.

Comment: That is the jsf-impl.jar 2.3.16.  Don't let Glassfish or the jakarta namespace throw you off. That is Mojarra 2.3.16

Comment: I dont think that is Mojarra or PF related, thats your error: 
Target Unreachable, identifier 'tabsChangesController' resolved to null

Comment: @tandraschkoI think you're both right. I need to refactor my code. Thanks for your efforts.